# Changing color value for css syntax when using tab completion via emmet

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-emmet-vim

Im using vim 7.4 and the Emmet plugin.

While editing a css document and entering a selector `.mylink` for example, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> will typically yield a space, opening and closing braces and a blank line where the cursor is positionned to start adding rules. This is great and creates something like this:

```
.mylink {
    |
}
```

*In this case the `|` represents the cursor postion*

#### Setting the rule

If I declare a background color, by entering <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> it creates:

```
.mylink {
    background: #|000;
}
```

*Again the `|` represents the cursor position*

#### The issue

While the cursor is positioned on the first character of the default `000`, if I start to enter a new value it just acts as an insert. Is there any way to change that functionality?

I would almost prefer it just default to the `#` and let me enter my value rather than having to escape and <kbd>cw</kbd> or something else to effectively reverse part of what the completion gives me. Or better yet, have it default to the `000` being visually selected so that I could opt to keep the default in the rare event I wanted black.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.